# Convergence of product of continuous functions and test functions

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I suspect the following result is true but I"m not sure how to go about proving:

It is given that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an open bounded, connected domain.(Not sure if theses conditions on the domain are important)

If $\{v_{n}\}_{n} \subset C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ such that $v_{n} \rightarrow v$ in $L^{1}(\Omega)$. Does it follow that for $f \in C(\Omega)$($f$ is continuous) that $fv_{n} \rightarrow fv$ in $L^{1}(\Omega)$?

thanks for any assistance

Comment: Look for a counterexample. Say with $v \equiv 1$.

Comment: Since $f$ is only continuous on the open domain it can grow arbitrarily fast at the boundary, even for $\Omega=(0,1)$. If $\Omega$ is compact this is true even for $f\in L^\infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay I see. Could you give me a hint as to how you would define the $v_{n}$ if you are taking $v = 1$.

Comment: Exhaust $\Omega$ by compact sets $K_n$ and let $v_n$ be a cutoff function for $K_n$ ($v_n\lvert_{K_n} \equiv 1$, $0 \leqslant v_n(x) \leqslant 1$, and $v_n$ has compact support in $\Omega$).

Comment: This would be (rather trivially) true if $f\in L^\infty(\Omega)\)$, without any other assumption.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Okay I see, it follows since $L^{\infty}{\Omega}$ is the continuous dual of $L^{1}(\Omega)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry for too much questions, but I haven't found a good reference for describing how to construct cut-off functions. I am going to suggest that $K_{n} := \{x \in \Omega: \text{dist}(x,\partial\Omega) \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$ is the compact sets invading $\Omega$. How do you construct cut-off functions for an arbitrary domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: Yes, that is a standard choice for the $K_n$. To construct the $v_n$, convolve the characteristic function $\chi_{K_{n+1}}$ of $K_{n+1}$ with a mollifier with small enough support.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay so say you take the mollification $\chi^{\epsilon}_{k} := \eta_{\epsilon}\ast \chi_{k}$(where $\eta$ is the standard mollifier). I can see that $\chi^{\epsilon}_{k}$ will be smooth but will it still have compact support and as a mollification the domain reduces, so will it still be defined on all of $\Omega$?

Comment: It will have compact support in $\Omega$ for small enough $\varepsilon$. Note that both $\chi_K$ and $\eta_\varepsilon$ are defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so the convolution too. Restrict to $\Omega$. Or, with the reduction-of-domain point of view, note that $\eta_\varepsilon \ast \chi_K$ vanishes in a neighbourhood of the boundary of the reduced domain, thus can be smoothly extended to all of $\Omega$ by $0$. The crucial thing here is that $\chi_K$ vanishes in a neighbourhood of the boundary of $\Omega$.